# Firestore - how to get the total number of records in a collection like we are doing in sql

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) { 
console.log(querySnapshot.size); });
```

but the problem is I am using **pagination** and load 30 records for each call. so I am unable to get the total numbers of records. Is there any way to get it ? like, we are doing in sql.

Comment: You want the total number from the API or the local storage ?

Comment: I understand that you want to get the TOTAL number of records of the collection. The code you mention at the beginning of your questions does exactly that. Which other number do you want?

Comment: There is no simple API to count documents in a collection.  You will have to put some work into maintaining a document count in a scalable way.

Comment: please can you elaborate it. " You will have to put some work into maintaining a document count in a scalable way"  where can I find it?

Comment: @DougStevenson Hello, could you please further develop your comment on the fact that "here is no simple API to count documents in a collection.". If I am not mistaking querying the **entire** collection and using `snapshot.size` returns the number of docs in the collection. With your comment, do you mean that it may cost a lot if the collection is large and therefore it is not a recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the total number of records in a collection with Firebase ?

The method `numChildren()` do that. You can find more information about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#numChildren)

Here is an example to use it:

```
db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) { 
    console.log(querySnapshot.numChildren());
});
```

I hope my answer help you

Comment: If I am not mistaking, the OP is using Firestore and not the Realtime Database.

Comment: He want to total number stored or the total on the API, sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: Indeed, IMHO, the OP question is not crystal clear but in your answer you mix up the Realtime Database with Firestore. `numChildren` is a method of the Realtime Database, not of Firestore. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#numChildren. The Firestore equivalent is `snapshot.size`, as the OP has noticed.

Comment: That’s true, I think he need to tell us more information, but as you say I think I’ve misunderstood the question

Comment: sorry I have missed the limit here. actually I am using load more, first time load 30 records and then on every load i am getting 30 records using "FlatList".
db.collection("cities").limit(30).get().then(function(querySnapshot) { 
    console.log(querySnapshot.numChildren());
});
here every time i am getting 30, but I need all count( total number of records)

Comment: Can make another query to get the number ?

Comment: You want the total number of record in your FlatList or on the server ?

Comment: @JulienKode on server

Comment: You can my solution but, do not paginante the query

Comment: @JulienKode as far as I search for two days, I reached the conclusion that there is no API call to get the count from the server. there is only one way, get all the data from firestore server and find its size like (querySnapshot.docs.length).which is a big drawback of firestore.