# Firestore - How to find the count of documents that can be fetched using a query without really fetching all documents?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Actually I want to create a Admin Panel for my website and I need to show the total number of users that signed up today(or in the last week). I want to fetch the number of user documents that were created in the *users* collection today. I have a *createdOn* field in every user document.

Can I do something like this:

```
admin.firestore()
  .collection('user')
  .where('createdOn', '>', <today's midnight timestamp here>)
  .count()
```

Like is there any hack/solution for fetching count of documents without actually fetching them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud Firestore collection count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554091/cloud-firestore-collection-count)

Comment: Or in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no `COUNT()`in Firestore (as yet) you are forced to query your documents to calculate or maintain the total number of records globally or based on arguments.

There is an [extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-counter) to do just that but I had trouble configuring it.

I personaly use a simple Cloud functions that I know is not completely bulletproof but good enough to provide me with a `dbutils` collection where I store the latest count of any collection. I also maintain `count` subcollections to store the number of records for the same collection but with query parameters. Quite necessary to propose a REST API...

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

export const dbutils = functions
   .firestore.document('/{collection}/{id}')
   .onWrite((change, context) => {
      const db = admin.firestore()
      const docRef = `dbutils/${context.params.collection}`
      let value = 0

      if (!change.before.exists) {
         value += 1 // new record
      } else if (!change.after.exists) {
         value -= 1 // deleted record
      }
      // ignore last case which is update

      if (value !== 0) {
         db.doc(docRef)
            .set(
               {
                  count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(value),
                  updatedAt: Date.now(),
               },
               { merge: true },
            )
            .then(res => deleteCollection(db, `${docRef}/counts`, 500))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }

      return null
   })

const deleteCollection = (
   db: admin.firestore.Firestore,
   collectionPath: string,
   batchSize: number,
) => {
   const collectionRef = db.collection(collectionPath)
   const query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize)

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject)
   })
}
```

I'm confident we'll get a `COUNT()` sooner or later!